# DS3_V2 VM Does not show me to resize from Standard D3

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM running Windows Server 2012 R2 and it is a Standards D3 VM I need to resize it to DS3_V2 VM but I can't see it in the sizing panel VM list. What I can see is bellow. What is the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Try to stop the VM and resize it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the virtual machine’s current host cluster hardware doesn’t support the new series, so it’s not listed as an option.

> By deallocating the virtual machine (Azure shutdown, not a guest OS
>   shutdown), all of the possible options in the region are made
>   available, and the resize process will migrate the virtual machine to
>   a new computer cluster.

Get more details from [this article](https://www.petri.com/resize-azure-virtual-machine).

Answer (score 0):

Deallocating also does not gives the above options. In my case, I did deallocate it and then powered on and again deallocated again then it's showing all sizes available.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a workaround. Do you have any idea why some sizes are not available? maybe there's a good reason why they're not available